# Building project with maven containing other projects

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I have a web-project A dependent on project B,

Project B dependent on JAR C

the problem:

When I package the web-project A, there is a jar for b (expected), but their is no reference to jar c

So, when I run my web-project A and access function the project B do I got class `NotFoundException` because jar C is not included

Any help how can I include jar C in parent project A without writing it myself in project A `pom.xml`

web-project `pom.xml`

```
<project ....>
    ..........
    <dependencies>
        <!--Local Projects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>project B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

project B `pom.xml`

```
<project ....>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jar_C</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar_C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you give us more info. Show the actual dependencies defined in the poms.

Comment: i edited the code to show my pom.xml

Comment: Is this a multi module project? In other words, is project C already built before B and B before A?

Comment: yab it's a multi module project, project B is built before A and C is just a jar i use

Comment: You didn't by accident specify the dependency in dependencyManagement as a test (or provided) dependency?

Comment: Another possibility is that you are referencing a class defined in src/test/java. Eclipse does not see the difference between test and main, but maven does.

Comment: nop , my problem is i don't know how to package a jar (project B) with it's own jars (jar c)

Comment: You want the dependencies included in the jar?

Comment: yab i don't know how to add dependencies to my own jar(project B)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21989/discussion-between-s-hawary-and-asgoth)

Answer (score 0):

As your configuration, Maven is just responsible for the compilation, that is to say a jar won't take any of its dependencies with itself. If you need to wrap up the dependencies all together, you should use the Assembly plugin, see:[here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a read at the [Maven Dependency Mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

***import*** (only available in Maven 2.0.9 or later)

This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the `<dependencyManagement>` section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's `<dependencyManagement>` section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

So Basically, try this

web-project `pom.xml`

```
<project ....>
    ..........
    <dependencies>
        <!--Local Projects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>project B</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```